# Data appears when printed but doesn't show up in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

```
#! /usr/lib/python3

import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None)

# Request stock data from yfinance
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')

# Get all option expiration dates in the form of a list
xdates = ticker.options

# Go through the list of expiry dates one by one
for xdate in xdates:
    # Get option chain info for that xdate
    option = ticker.option_chain(xdate)
    # print out this value, get back 15 columns and 63 rows of information
    print(option)
    # Put that same data in dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = option)
    # Show dataframe
    print(df)
```

Expected: `df` will show a `DataFrame` containing the same information that is shown when running `print(option)`, i.e. 15 columns and 63 rows of data, or at least some part of them

Actual:

- `df` shows only two columns with no information
- `df.shape` results in `(2,1)`
- `print(df.columns.tolist())` results in `[0]`

Since the desired info appears when you print it, I'm confused as to why it's not appearing in the dataframe.

Comment: in this example `option` is not a valid input to create pandas dataframe, or at least not the way you're expecting it. Can you show some desired/expected output the way you need it to be in pandas.DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of `option_chain` for specific expiration date is avaialable in `calls` property of the object as dataframe. You don't have to create a new dataframe.

```
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
xdates = ticker.options
option = ticker.option_chain(xdates[0])
option.calls # DataFrame
```

[GitHub - yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance)